# Interface with partially/special/glob key names

Tags: typescript

Sorry about the subject of this post... it's hard for me to describe what I mean without an example.

I'm hooking in to an external API that has no TypeScript types for it, so I am making my own. One feature they have on their API is a filter system to search for resources, and this uses a special key value to determine what you want... and I want to create an interface for it.

It goes in the format of `name[operator]: value`, so some examples of this:

```
first_name[is]: "Bob"
last_name[is_not]: "Smith"
email[starts_with]: "roger@"
price[gt]: 123
// etc etc.
```

So what I want, in pseudo TypeScript code is something like:

```js
enum Operator {
  Is = "is",
  IsNot = "is_not",
  StartsWith = "starts_with",
}

interface IFilter {
  last_name[Operator]: string,
  email[Operator]: string,
}
```

Is something like this possible in TypeScript 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using mapped types:

```
enum Operator {
    Is = "is",
    IsNot = "is_not",
    StartsWith = "starts_with",
}

interface IFilter {
    last_name: Partial<Record<Operator, string>>
    email: Partial<Record<Operator, string>>
}
let f: IFilter = {
    email: {},
    last_name: {}
}
f.email[Operator.Is] = ""
```

You could even build a mapped type to take an existing type and map it into a filter type:

```
enum Operator {
    Is = "is",
    Gt = "gt",
    IsNot = "is_not",
    StartsWith = "starts_with",
}

type Filter<T> =  {
    [P in keyof T]: Partial<Record<Operator, T[P]>>
}

interface IPerson {
    email: string,
    last_name: string,
    age: number
}
let f: Filter<IPerson> = {
    email: {},
    last_name: {},
    age: {}
}
f.email[Operator.Is] = ""
f.age[Operator.Gt] = 1 //ok
f.age[Operator.Gt] = "1" //err
```